# Wordpress Jetpack Plugin - Wordpress Stats Buggy

Tags: wordpress, plugins, statistics

I have a problem with my Wordpress site. I installed Jetpack and it doesn't really look right.

See picture:

[image: Wordpress Jetpack Problem]

(http://indie-wok.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Bildschirmfoto-2012-11-12-um-18.01.08.png)

Has anyone else encountered this bug too? How can I fix it ?

Comment: No one know something? :/ I have tried some things but nothing worked !